# Memberships Due for Renewal for Mail Merge

Tags: renewals

We have recently upgraded to civicim 5.55.2. When we select Memberships Due for Renewal for Mail Merge we are taken back to the welcome screen.

Comment: perhaps share the link that it would go to - and see what happens at same url on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org or equivalent on other CMS

Comment: suggesting because it isn't obvious to me where this link goes, so wondering if it is a custom link

Comment: thank you, it was a custom link so now resolved

Comment: would you add that as an Answer to your own question. SE complains about Q that never get an A :-)

Answer (score 2):

thank you, it was a custom link so now resolved